# bazel inside of vagrant box creates read-only file system error message

Tags: vagrant, bazel

I am trying to run a bazel system inside of a vagrant box, but sadly run into this error:

```
Error: EROFS: read-only file system, open 'bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/ui/web/admin/src/src_transpiled/lib/typescript/types/global.d.js'
```

The project is using the `bazel-javascript` module to compile the javascript part of this project. It works fine on my machine, but as soon as I try it in the vagrant box it fails. Sadly I have no idea how to debug this and would love any help in figuring out what is wrong here.